# How to create count variable of a field using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

Can anyone tell me how easy to create a variable that consist of count of a field. so that we can use that variable to value expression of pie chart and the field in category expression of pie chart.

Comment: did you try 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_variables.htm

Comment: Yes Sebri, i tried the tutorial that you given aboove. however i didn't get correct counts of the field.please help me on this.

Comment: counts of the field ==> sum value of this field ?

Comment: No i don't want the sum of a field. I need to find the count of a field in iReport. For example i need to create a variable called "CallCount" which have count of "CallType" field. So i need to use "CallType" field in Category section of Piechart and "CallCount" variable as measure. So that pie chart will show the call types and its call counts

Comment: Can you post some section of jrxml file ?

Comment: </queryString>
 <field name="newSet1.DISP_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="newSet1.CALL" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <variable name="Callcount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="CallType" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="CallType" calculation="Count">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{CallType_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
  <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{CallType_COUNT}]]></initialValueExpression>
 </variable>
 <group name="CallType">
  <groupExpression><![CDATA[$P{CALL_TYPE_DESC_1}]]></groupExpression>
 </group>

Comment: did you try    <variableExpression>
       <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
   </variableExpression>

Comment: Yes, i tried variable expression as TRUE. still i am getting wrong count.please give me some other suggestions..

Comment: CALL_TYPE_DESC_1 is a parameter so you can prepare your count by type
CALL_TYPE_COUNT_1

Comment: I am getting the following error when i tried to use parameter for count "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable".

Comment: Hi Sebri, At last i tried your above comment i am getting the callcount which is sum of counts of all the CALL_TYPE_DESC as only one value. however i need count in different CALL_TYPE_DESC.

Comment: You should update your question with any additional requirements so people don't have to hunt through the comments.

Comment: Your are grouping by CallType.  Your variable would contain the total for each group.  If you are using this variable in your group footer, it should be giving you the correct total for each CallType.  Do you need these broken out at the end of the report for each CallType?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to create count variable in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104028/need-to-create-count-variable-in-ireport)